# Make Yammer feed display on a intranet site without enabling cookies on browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, feed, yammer, yammer-api

I can't display the yammer feed on an intranet website as the organization disabled cookies on browsers.

Is there any way to integrate the feed without enabling cookies ?

Tried using iframes and pure JavaScript snippets in the CMS and didn't work out.

```html
<iframe name="embed-feed" title="Yammer" src="https://web.yammer.com/embed/feed?header=false&footer=false&theme=light" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 400px;"></iframe>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
    <div id="embedded-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div> 
    <script>
        yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: 'fourleaf.com'  // network permalink (see below)
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```